# Rapidly serving multiple images from GAE datastore

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, http-headers

I'm using jinja to render a page filled with a variable number of images, using the format

```
<img src="/image?id=x" />
```

The image URL points to a hander that retrieves the relevant image from the datastore and returns it as a response, as described here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/serving_dynamic_images.html

The problem I'm having is that there is a small delay between each image being loaded, and each is loaded sequentially, meaning that a page with 50 images on it takes an unacceptable amount of time to load.

Does anyone know a way around this?  It feels like I should somehow have the server set up to run the image serving handler on multiple threads.

Comment: Is this on the dev server, or in production?

Comment: Good point, this is on the dev server

Comment: The dev server is single-threaded, and can't serve more than one file at a time. This is the expected behavior. (star http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=343 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Wobble pointed out, the dev_appserver.py server is single-threaded. The production server will be able to serve more than one image at any given time comfortably up to the limits of the browser.

But there is further advice: you should use URLs like /image_xxx.jpg or /images/xxx.jpg and send an expires header. That should prevent repeated downloads of your images. It would also make it easier to point a cache to your backend and serve cached versions of your images from there instead of from App Engine and your application.

These ideas should take you very far. If you hit that limit, you could hire a CDN service and put it in front of your cacheable images.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a limitation of AppEngine. AppEngine will scale automatically to serve the requests. However, browsers are limited to a certain number of simultaneous requests to the same hostname - this varies depending on the browser, and some allow the user to configure, but in most recent browsers the limit seems to be 6. See [this chart](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network) for more.

Now, the limit is per *hostname*, not per domain. So, you could actually make use of the fact that AppEngine will serve your app on any subdomain using the `FOO-dot-APPNAME` syntax. Eg, if your app is `myblog`, you can serve it on `img1-dot-myblog.appspot.com`, `img2-dot-myblog.appspot.com`, and so on, and these don't count as simultaneous connections from the point of view of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First read the answer of @Daniel Roseman. He is right to note that the limitation is on browser side. Modern desktop browsers limit parallel requests to 6 per domain or 35-40 in total.

To work around this:

1. Try fanning out requests for your images to multiple hostnames. You can simply do that on GAE by uploading to different versions, e.g. `img1.yourapp.appspot.com`, `img2.yourapp.appspot.com`, etc.. You can then simply generate the version prefix by appending the random range number to `img`.
2. If you have a somewhat fixed superset of images, than you can combine them in one image and refer to particular image via [image sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). This way you'd only have one large image downloaded in one request. You can combine images on App Engine by creating a composite `ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(image, ...)` and then combining composites into one image with `ImagesService.composite(composites, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using serving_urls in production so if you preset those urls you dont need to handle the serving of images on your side and they will load a lot faster.

once an image is uplaoded create a serving_url and set it on your entity so you will be able to put the url directly into the template without accessing a handler.

this wont change anything on your local machine using the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The article you refer to is very old. Use the fantastic High Speed Image API with:
get_serving_url(blob_key, size=None, crop=False)
And the images will be served by Google with **NO load** for your application and high speed.

I use a Jinja Function loader to generate the serving URL's. To give you an idea:
This template line :

```
<img  {% include "front=698.jpg" %} />
```

will be translated in something like:

```
<img   alt="front=698.jpg" src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-obCxGmlnWZFU-UGRTA6juHNpNPJ90-XafQsYdCW_53ANDlzA4l33n-DBvevcI4urHu9Qa205ZOx5YBg3IU=s698" />
```

You can even size the image at runtime. By the way : you have to upload your images to your application blobstore. But the serving is done by : google. with **NO LOAD**